# Android Project Compile Issues - From Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-speech-api

I am attempting to learn special functions of Android and have attempted to compile the app project listed below, but unfortunately it does not appear to compile on Android Studio.

Is anyone able to help on this issue?

It will be very beneficial for the wider community, as it teaches the workings of the various sensors such as speech etc. I am trying to follow the following book, but the author appears to have abandoned new updates:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-Android-Sensor-Programming-Programmer/dp/1118183487/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1448814695&sr=1-1&keywords=android+sensor

The link to the app project is as follows:
https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib

Thank you

> Information:Using javac 1.7.0_51 to compile java sources
>   Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'libraryLuceneExt'
>   Information:29/11/2015 18:31 - Compilation completed with 19 errors and 0 warnings in 8s 395ms
>   C:\Users*****\Desktop\gast-lib-master\gast-lib-master\libraryLuceneExt\src\root\gast\speech\lucene\LuceneIndexBuilder.java
>   Error:(18, 20) java: package android.util does not exist
>   Error:(58, 17) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexBuilder
>   Error:(68, 17) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexBuilder
>   Error:(88, 13) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexBuilder
>   Error:(92, 13) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexBuilder
>   Error:(96, 13) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexBuilder
>   Error:(110, 13) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexBuilder
>   Error:(126, 13) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexBuilder
>   Error:(138, 13) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexBuilder
>   Error:(143, 13) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexBuilder
>   Error:(153, 17) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexBuilder
>   Error:(157, 17) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexBuilder
>   C:\Users*****\Desktop\gast-lib-master\gast-lib-master\libraryLuceneExt\src\root\gast\speech\lucene\LuceneIndexSearcher.java
>   Error:(16, 20) java: package android.util does not exist
>   Error:(62, 9) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexSearcher
>   Error:(72, 17) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexSearcher
>   Error:(80, 17) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.LuceneIndexSearcher
>   C:\Users*****\Desktop\gast-lib-master\gast-lib-master\libraryLuceneExt\src\root\gast\speech\lucene\RecognitionIndexer.java
>   Error:(12, 20) java: package android.util does not exist
>   Error:(59, 17) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.RecognitionIndexer
>   Error:(67, 17) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable Log
>     location: class root.gast.speech.lucene.RecognitionIndexer

Comment: "Does not compile" is not very helpful. Do you get any error ? If so post your logcat.

Comment: Thanks, just added the messages from Logcat